# Python - Nested Loop Multiplication Matrix

Tags: python, loops, matrix, nested

[image]

Evening!

My goal is to get something similar to what is shown above using nested loops. I understand that nested loops are just another loop within another. I know that I must use a range for the top row and side column. However, I’m not sure how to whip up the math equation to output the factors of each number.

This is what I have and I’m seriously struggling.

```
def main():
  for num in range(10):
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            print(num, end=‘’)
    print()
main()
```

Comment: So the first column is just `range(1,10)` right? Then the second column is just `range(1,10)` but multiplied by two, and so on. Or you can view it row-wise instead, it's equivalent. You definitely only need two loops here, not three.

Comment: `[[x*i for x in range(1,10)] for i in range(1,10)]` will give you the 2-D array.

Comment: `print('\n'.join( [' '.join([str(x) for x in row]) for row in arr]))`

Comment: I’m not quite to that level yet, haha.

Comment: `print('\n'.join( [' '.join(['%2d'%(x) for x in row]) for row in arr]))` will pretty print

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this in two steps (it's just more clear). First, generate the 2D matrix, and then print it. To generate the matrix, you can use a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
>>> M = [[row*col for col in range(1,10)] for row in range(1,10)]
```

This is equivalent to the double `for` loop, but it's easier since you don't have to initialize the matrix `M`. These are used everywhere in Python, so get used to them quickly! It's fairly easy to understand. For example,

```
>>> [i for i in range(1,10)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This is what the inner loop is doing, but then it multiplies those values by the `row` value for each row for the outer row.

Then to print, simply loop over the rows in the matrix and `join` the row together. If you're using Python 3.6+, you can use [`f-strings` (*literal string interpolation)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) for printing:

```
>>> for row in M:
...     print(''.join([f'{val:>4}' for val in row]))
```

If you're on an older version of Python, then use string formatting:

```
>>> for row in M:
...     print(''.join(['{val:>4}'.format(val=val) for val in row]))
```

In both cases, `:>4` means to use a string of fixed width at 4 aligned right, where `>` means right-align, and `4` is the fixed width. These both result in:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18
   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27
   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36
   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54
   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63
   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72
   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81
```

But to do it in a single step, not storing the matrix `M`, you can simply do:

```
print('\n'.join([''.join([f'{row*col:>4}' for col in range(1,10)]) for row in range(1,10)]))
```

Note that `join` here joins strings together. So in the inner loop, it's joining together all the numbers `row*col` with their fixed-width right-aligned representation for each column inside a row, and then it's joining together those rows with a new line separator for each row.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is a simple product, `x*y`, and note, the `range` iterates over *a numerical range already*, you don't need `num`:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 10):
...     for j in range(1, 10):
...         product = i*j
...         print(f"{product:>3}", end='')
...     print() # just prints a newline
...
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18
  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27
  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36
  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
  6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54
  7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63
  8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72
  9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

I use f-strings, a nice new feature available in Python 3.6

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for the format-specification that I used, `{var:>3}`, which right justifies your string by 3 spaces.

Also, this is a great reference:

https://pyformat.info/

Unfortunately, there are *three* seperate ways of doing string formatting in Python. Quite frankly, f-strings are rapidly becoming my preferred way, and I think it's great if you don't abuse them, since they can take any *expression*

Comment: Any suggestions on how to format since I’m stuck on 3.5 at the moment? I’ve been trying to use the standard format() but I can’t seem to get it to work.

Comment: @GoldDial sure. `.format` uses numbers that represent the "ith" argument, in the simplest approch `"{0:>3}".format(product)`, or since you only have 1 argument, you can actually just use `"{:>3}".format(product)`